# What is the right CSV encoding for c# to open with Excel?

Tags: c#, excel, csv, encoding, streamwriter

I write a CSV with my C# CSVWriter based on a StreamWriter.
In my data I have a lot of special characters like "Bávaro".

So when I use UTF-8 or ASCII to encode my CSV I can't get the "á" but I can open it in Excel afterwards perfectly.
When I use Unicode my CSV has the correct char but in fact when I open this CSV in Excel it doesnt get automaticly sorted like my other CSV, all values are in the first column as string....

What is the right encoding here?

Comment: Excel can open CSV encoded in UTF-8 only with the correct encoding if the CSV file contains a BOM at its beginning. Unicode (UTF-16) encoded CSV will only be opened correctly if they are tabulator delimited and not comma (or semicolon) delimited.

Comment: Try to add preamble bytes to file, as I wrote here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46076517/908936

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend using [Windows ANSI Codepage 1252](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) which you can get via:

```
Encoding.GetEncoding(1252)
```

It supports characters like "á" and works well from Excel 2003 to Excel 2013.

Answer (score 1):

Export your CSV using this encoding `Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252")`