# C# - format column when writing to CSV file(cell formatting)

Tags: c#, .net, string

Have written the method for the exporting the data to csv files.
  If the value of the cell has `DEC20` in csv is getting as `20-Dec` which is not correct.

My code is like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myData.Count(); i++)
{
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, 
                              Common.FormatExportString(myData[i].Code),
                              Common.FormatExportString(myData[i].Name),
                              Common.FormatExportString(myData[i].Description)));
}
//returns the file after writing the stream to the csv file.
return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(sb.ToString()), "text/csv", fileName);
```

Kindly help me to get the exact `string` format to be displayed in the excel (csv) file using C#.

Ex: 
myData[i].Name data will be

> DEC20, or 2-5

like this,

but the output in csv(excel) is getting displayed as

> 20-Dec and 5-May

instead of the original one.

Comment: what is the type of myData[i].Description? And what does FormatExportString() do?

Comment: that is just a method for replacing the , inside the cell value

Comment: a complete example can help, can you show what's inside myData[i] + what's the resultant sb + what's the resultant file content?

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is with your exporter? It's not Excel changing the format when it loads your (correctly formatted) CSV file? Open the CSV file in Notepad and check.

Comment: Yep I think Carson63000 is right, try to open the csv with notepad

Comment: This has nothing to do with .csv, it's an excel thing. Basically excel thinks that the value is a date, and displays it as such.

Comment: Yes in notepad it is getting the proper data problem with the autoformatting of the microsoft excel..

Comment: you can avoid this putting wrapping the text with quotes

Comment: @trippino Can you show that how to do?

Answer (score 12):

The problem is not concerning the csv exportation, if you open the csv file with notepad it is well formed. It is Excel that auto-detects the cell type as a date and shows it as a date.

To avoid this behavior wrap the text between quotes and put a `=` before it, as shown below:

```
= "DEC20"
```

The file should became as

```
= "field1", = "field2", = "field...", = "DEC20", ...
```

Your method should become:

```
for (int i = 0; i < myData.Count(); i++)
{
    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(delimiter, 
                              " = \"",
                              Common.FormatExportString(myData[i].Code),
                              Common.FormatExportString(myData[i].Name),
                              Common.FormatExportString(myData[i].Description)
                              "\""));
}

//returns the file after writing the stream to the csv file.
return File(new System.Text.UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(sb.ToString()), "text/csv", fileName);
```

Comment: try to add a '=' before the text, I've edited the answer to explain better

Comment: So it can be like this?  `actualValue=field1; returnValue="=\""+field1+"\"";`

Comment: nope, it's not necessary to add 'actualValue'; you can simply put a '=' before printing the field between quotes, example: ="field1", = "field2", = "DEC20", ecc...

Comment: In C# code actually i cant add directly like this, so included that in the format method, but somewhere the string is collapsed.

Comment: Ahn I thought you was speaking about the csv file, I've edited the answer with some code you can try.

Comment: Actually, i have added '=' for all variables, it is occuring as the inconsistence formula error (warning) excel while getting displayed. WE can ignor it, but is there any way to resolve it in a good manner

Answer (score 2):

CSV is a very simple format that will allow Excel to apply default formats on the text. 
I suggest you write your Excel file without the use of CSV, but Excel API You should specify how you want to format the cells.

The Excel COM object will allow you to write native Excel file. You can read about it here:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/ef11a193-54f3-407b-9374-9f5770fd9fd7

Comment: but what if you dont have Excel on the machine?

Comment: can be opened using the notepad.. if it is the notepad can be |pipe delimited which occurs like pipe separated characters

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not the CSV Output,

The issue is that Excel is "Too Smart for it's own good" and automatically detects the data-type and deduce that DEC20 is "December 20", even though it is not!

you can instruct Excel of a Text column by adding a ' before the text.
as
`"'my Val", "'Dec10", "'54/40/2042", "'22/7/2013", "439.54"`

All these will be treated as Text, and not Date/Numeric or anything else.

Cheers

Comment: but the problem faced was, the data should be exact and it should be displayed without change, so that, like considered to be string .. ur answer is also found helpful.. but the above idea is one more good idea, which will work for dynamic situations.. thanks all.. :)

Comment: Though in the CSV there will be the ' char,
excel wont show it...
but yes, the ="fdgd"  is a good solution as well :)

Answer (score 0):

If the string is being collapsed, should manipulate the strings in the right way to be accepted by excel.

if the string has, single quotes('') add "'ur string'" and with overall string should be within the `="your string with so all special characters and the commas"`

Comment: ok but will it be applicable for the special characters like chinese char also?

Comment: Please refer this for the same.., http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3346529/c-excel-csv-how-to-get-the-correct-encoding