# Add byte order mark to a string via StringBuilder

Tags: c#, utf-8, stringbuilder, byte-order-mark

How can I add a byte order mark to a StringBuilder?
(I have to pass a string to another method which will save it as a file, but I can't modify that method).

I tried this:

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append('\xEF');
sb.Append('\xBB');
sb.Append('\xBF');
```

But when I view it with hex editor, it adds the following sequence:
`C3 AF C2 BB C2 BF`

The string is huge, so it would be good to do it without back and forth converting to byte array.

**Edit:**
Clarification after questions in comments. I have to pass the string to another method which takes a string and creates a file of it on Azure Blob Storage. I can't modify the other method.

Comment: Why?  The byte order mark isn't needed until you write to a file...  The issue you see is because the byte order marks *are not Unicode*.

Comment: I have to pass the string to another method which takes a string and creates a file of it on Azure Blob Storage.

Comment: For anyone that's using `File.WriteAllText()` - it supports setting the encoding to UTF8 which will add a BOM. See:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writealltext?view=net-8.0#system-io-file-writealltext(system-string-system-string-system-text-encoding)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Two options:

1. Don't include the byte order mark in your *text* at all... instead use an encoding which will automatically include it
2. Include it *as a character* in your `StringBuilder`:

   ```
   sb.Append('\uFEFF'); // U+FEFF is the byte-order mark character
   ```

Personally I'd go for the first approach normally, but the "I can't modify that method" suggests it may not be an option in your case.

Comment: Thank you. Yes, you are right, I'd go for the first one normally, but I'm taking this approach beacuse I have to pass the string to another method which takes a string and creates a file of it on Azure Blob Storage.

Answer (score 8):

Byte-order marks are to inform readers of a file that the file is of a particular encoding.  As such, you should only need the byte-order marks (BOM) in the actual file.  If you want to include BOM in a text file you're writing, simply use `StreamWriter` to write to the file.  For example:

```
using(var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8))
{
    writer.Write(sb.ToString);
}
```

If you don't want BOM with UTF-8:

```
using(var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
{
    writer.Write(sb.ToString());
}
```

Or if you want different BOM:

```
using(var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF16))
{
    writer.Write(sb.ToString);
}
```

## Update:

If you wanted to be coupled from the implementation detail of a BOM or a BOM of a particular encoding (i.e. could change at runtime or after deployment) but still wanted to pass a BOM-marked string, you could do something like this (assumes .NET 4.5):

```
var stream = new MemoryStream();
var encoding = Encoding.UTF8; // TODO: configurize this, if necessary
using(var writer = new StreamWriter(stream, encoding, 1024, true))
{
    writer.Write(sb.ToString());
}
CantModifyButMustUseThis(encoding.GetString(stream.ToArray());
```

Comment: I am aware what BOM is for. However, as I mentioned in my question, I must pass it to another method (which takes a string and creates a file of it on Azure Blob Storage), that's why I am taking this approach.

Comment: This is misleading. For example, with UTF-8 and `StreamWriter`, if you leave out the `encoding` constructor argument entirely or if you use `new UTF8Encoding()` as the argument, then UTF-8 ***without*** the byte-order-mark is produced. On the other hand, if you specify the argument as `Encoding.UTF8` or as `new UTF8Encoding(true)` you get UTF-8 ***with*** BOM. This is a bit of a gotcha, actually. So your first example is wrong.

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes, you are correct.  I've modified by answer.

Comment: @user2270404 The `stream` used by `StreamWriter` does not need to be a file stream.

Comment: @Peter Ritchie: I understand, but how can I pass the output of your solution to `CantModifyButMustUseThis(string content)` ?

Comment: @user2270404 I've added an update to the answer; but, I would push hard to use a stream in methods like this. e.g. what if the string was too large to fit in memory?

Comment: There is no `Encoding.UTF16` in dotnet core, use `Encoding.Unicode` instead.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC (and not certain that I do), BOM gets added when you convert to byte using one of the relevant Unicode Encoders.  I believe [some of UnicodeEncoding's constructors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.unicodeencoding.-ctor) take a bool that control if to add BOM.  For example, calling the constructor `public UnicodeEncoding (bool bigEndian, bool byteOrderMark);` and setting the argument `byteOrderMark` to `true` should cause BOM to be emitted during serialization of your string.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/35205629)

Comment: @Ouroborus, I made the edit -- that should address it, I hope?

Answer (score 0):

I used this code in ASP.NET core, and well!! it works

```
 [HttpGet("GetCsv")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> GetCsv() {
        
        var cc = new CsvConfiguration(new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US"));
        var entity = await _service.AdminPanelList();
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream()) {
            using (var sw = new StreamWriter(stream: ms, encoding: new UTF8Encoding(true))) {
                using (var cw = new CsvWriter(sw, cc)) {

                    var bom = '\uFEFF'.ToString();
                    byte[] bomArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(bom);
                    
                    ms.Write(bomArray);
                    cw.WriteRecords(entity);
                }

                var finalArray = ms.ToArray();
                



                var result = File(finalArray, "text/csv", $"PersonExport.csv");
                    

                return result;
            }
        }
    }
```